# Split my string as per specific requirement

Tags: c#, parsing

I have written a small method that extracts certain information from a string. An example of such a string is

```
"Author: rajdra1 Subject: Sticky Note  Date: 09-08-2018 11:06:56"
```

Now I need certain information from this string into my string array, e.g. the Author, Subject, Date.

My methode -

```
Public void SplitString()
{
  string input = "Author: rajdra1 Subject: Sticky Note  Date: 09-08-2018 
                  11:06:56";

  string[] result = input.Split(new string[] {": "},
```

StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

```
  foreach (var value in result)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(value);
    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

I'm getting a result like:

```
{"rajdra1 Subject",  "Sticky Note  Date", "09-08-2018 11:06:56"}
```

But my expected output is:

```
{"rajdra1", "Sticky Note", "09-08-2018 11:06:56"}
```

Actually, I take this input from .txt file and I always get input in below format

```
"Author: rajdra1 Subject: Sticky Note  Date: 09-08-2018 11:06:56"
```

where I am considering "Author", "Subject" and "Date" as the column header
and I wanted to add the expected result under a specific header.

Comment: Can you advise what you've tried so far and why it falls short of your expectations?

Comment: You've already written the method to extract the information so what issues are you having?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to write method but I am getting confusion that how should split this string so I will get my expected result

Comment: How you are getting the input? is that in your control?

Comment: Are you *sure* that those blank spaces in your string are *all* just normal spaces? Because that would mean it's an extremely crappy format and I'd suggest not working with that vendor ever again. If however, the white space right before the field name is in fact a [tab] character, then this would be dead easy to split and parse.

Comment: this is my 1st time that I am asking the question here so sorry if any mistake..

Comment: Hi @SammedBagwade, welcome to SO. Don't worry too much about the downvotes and comments, just answer them as well as possible, and update your question to make it as clear as you can, and they will be balanced out eventually. In the future, please try to include as complete an example as possible in your question from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Extracting autor, subject and date from this string can be done using Regular Expressions:

```
var myRegex = new Regex(@"Author:\s+(?<author>.*)\sSubject:\s+(?<subject>.*)\s+Date:\s+(?<date>.*)", RegexOptions.None);
var strTargetString = @"Author: rajdra1 Subject: Sticky Note  Date: 09-08-2018 11:06:56";

var str = new string[3];
foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
      str[0] = myMatch.Groups["author"].Value;
      str[1] = myMatch.Groups["subject"].Value;
      str[2] = myMatch.Groups["date"].Value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this but when I am debugging, debug point never going inside foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat long, but still fairly simple and safe way to do this is to search and split the string explicitly for each part you are looking for:

```
var input = "Author: rajdra1 Subject: Sticky Note  Date: 09-08-2018 11:06:56" ;
// For the sake of example; this will also work:
//var input = "Author: Someone Else Subject: Another note.  Date: 09-08-2018 11:06:56" ;

var datePos = input.IndexOf("Date:");
// get: Date: 09-08-2018 11:06:56
var datePart = input.Substring(datePos);

var subjectPos = input.IndexOf("Subject:");
var subjectPartLength = datePos - subjectPos;
// get: Subject: Sticky Note  
var subjectPart = input.Substring(subjectPos, subjectPartLength);

var authorPos = 0;
var authorLength = subjectPos;
// get: Author: rajdra1
var authorPart = input.Substring(authorPos, authorLength);

// Add each of the above, but skipping over the first part of each:
var result = new string[]{
                    authorPart.Substring(8), 
                    subjectPart.Substring(9), 
                    datePart.Substring(6) 
              };
```

This assumes there will be a space after each "column title". If that is wrong, just change the number passed to `Substring()` in the last line.